# "Oh no!" gnome-shell exiting on startup

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell

This is a fresh (not upgrade) 20.04.2 LTS install. When the system boots up, the console displays the dreaded (and unhelpfully [non-specific](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-session/-/issues/62)) "Oh no! Something has gone wrong" screen.

Before the details, I do want to note that this image was built on a small lab server (where it's warmer and more comfortable!) and then the disk installed on a different system (different CPU, Video, etc) so that may have something to do with it. It still runs fine if I take it back to the lab. I recall seeing a message during install about "configuring for your hardware" so it may be a configuration or driver issue, but I can't find a tool to "rescan" when it's on the production server. I can log in via ssh or a non-GUI VT, only get the "Oh No" on the gnome login screen.

The video uses the radeon driver

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: ES1000
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=64 mingnt=8
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0000000-f7ffffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:fcbf0000-fcbfffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

... and it appears that the radeon driver is loaded

```
$ lsmod | grep radeon
radeon               1466368  2
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
ttm                   102400  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 radeon
drm                   552960  5 drm_kms_helper,radeon,ttm
```

and is in use

```
$ dmesg | grep -i radeon
[   14.765323] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   15.509574] fb0: switching to radeondrmfb from VESA VGA
[   17.906464] radeon 0000:01:05.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   17.908262] radeon 0000:01:05.0: VRAM: 128M 0x00000000F0000000 - 0x00000000F7FFFFFF (16M used)
[   17.908267] radeon 0000:01:05.0: GTT: 512M 0x00000000D0000000 - 0x00000000EFFFFFFF
[   17.908411] [drm] radeon: 16M of VRAM memory ready
[   17.908413] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
[   17.929587] radeon 0000:01:05.0: WB disabled
[   17.929593] radeon 0000:01:05.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x00000000d0000000 and cpu addr 0x(____ptrval____)
[   17.929635] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   17.930135] [drm] radeon: ring at 0x00000000D0001000
[   17.931067] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   18.017858] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   18.192362] radeon 0000:01:05.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   18.215817] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:05.0 on minor 0
```

After digging through dmesg, and the various logs, I think I've narrowed it down to this bit in syslog (edited to remove messages from other subsystems and added ellipses ... for repeated/similar lines).

Some things that caught my eye were:

- libGL error: failed to create dri screen
- libGL error: failed to load driver: radeon
- traps: gnome-shell[2221] trap invalid opcode ip:7ff7d2f7b43c sp:7ffe95253200 error:0

```
Feb 20 12:52:54 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
Feb 20 12:52:54 ubuntu4 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1067]: (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "PGS", prod id 779
Feb 20 12:52:54 ubuntu4 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1067]: (II) RADEON(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 0x316 mode
Feb 20 12:52:54 ubuntu4 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1067]: (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Feb 20 12:52:54 ubuntu4 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1067]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
...
Feb 20 12:52:54 ubuntu4 gnome-shell[2221]: libGL error: failed to create dri screen
Feb 20 12:52:54 ubuntu4 gnome-shell[2221]: libGL error: failed to load driver: radeon
Feb 20 12:52:54 ubuntu4 gsd-media-keys[1645]: Failed to grab accelerators: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.gnome.Shell” on object at path /org/gnome/Shell
Feb 20 12:52:55 ubuntu4 gnome-shell[2221]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Feb 20 12:52:55 ubuntu4 gnome-shell[2221]: Will monitor session 2
Feb 20 12:52:55 ubuntu4 gsd-media-keys[1645]: Failed to grab accelerators: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.gnome.Shell” on object at path /org/gnome/Shell
Feb 20 12:52:55 ubuntu4 dbus-daemon[1070]: [session uid=1000 pid=1070] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.IBus' requested by ':1.100' (uid=1000 pid=2783 comm="ibus-daemon --panel disable --xim " label="unconfined")
Feb 20 12:52:55 ubuntu4 dbus-daemon[1070]: [session uid=1000 pid=1070] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.IBus'
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 gnome-shell[2221]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 colord[1757]: failed to get session [pid 753]: No data available
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 gnome-shell[2221]: Failed to create file /run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions: Error opening file “/run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions”: File exists
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 dbus-daemon[1070]: [session uid=1000 pid=1070] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.Notifications' requested by ':1.98' (uid=1000 pid=2221 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 dbus-daemon[1070]: [session uid=1000 pid=1070] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.Notifications'
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Started GNOME Shell on X11.
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Reached target GNOME Shell on X11.
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Reached target GNOME X11 Session.
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Reached target GNOME X11 Session (session: ubuntu).
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1613854376.7398] agent-manager: agent[75d0de6dc9ef5eaa,:1.68/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 gnome-shell[2221]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 gsd-media-keys[1645]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
...
Feb 20 12:52:56 ubuntu4 gnome-shell[2221]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
...
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 kernel: [   18.029584] traps: gnome-shell[2221] trap invalid opcode ip:7ff7d2f7b43c sp:7ffe95253200 error:0
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Stopped target GNOME X11 Session (session: ubuntu).
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Stopping GNOME X11 Session (session: ubuntu).
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Stopped target GNOME X11 Session.
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Stopping GNOME X11 Session.
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Stopped target GNOME Shell on X11.
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Stopping GNOME Shell on X11.
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Feb 20 12:52:57 ubuntu4 systemd[1028]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
[manual edit ... this cycle repeats three times...]
```

Comment: Did you install Radeon video drivers on the build system? Does this system have the same video card? Have you installed any gnome-shell extensions?

Comment: @heynnema - I did not explicitly load the Radeon drivers, but it looks like they are included in the base distribution. I updated the question above with more details. The production system (details above) have different video than the lab system. I have not added any gnome-shell extensions -- the only ones there would be the ones included in the base install.

Comment: If the Radeon card in one machine is different than the Radeon card in the other machine, there's a good chance that any installed driver may be wrong. Try uninstalling the Radeon driver and see if the machine will boot... or, if the computer also has built-in video, just remove the Radeon card, move the video cable to the proper port connector, and see if the machine then boots.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to rename the user directory, then recreate it empty and set proper permissions. After login I restored the important documents and settings.
Later I figured the problem was caused because I restored the VHD from another computer, where the same VM was configured to use newer Hyper-V configuration 9.0 instead of 8.0. Upgrading the configuration would have been sufficient since it worked just fine right before I copied the VHD.

Comment: I'm having a somewhat similar problem - I'm running a 20.04 image, cloned by Clonezilla from a virtual machine in KVM, running in Ubuntu 21.04.

If I run this image in KVM ( virt-manager) in Ubuntu 20.04, I get the "Oh no!"-screen - but only for one of the two users on the image, the one that was used to configure the PC. The other user works fine.

As you say, it might easily be because the versions of the virtualization systems.

Answer (score 0):

Here removing the mesa_shader_cache directory did the trick:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/gdm3/.cache/mesa_shader_cache
rm -rf $HOME/.cache/mesa_shader_cache
```

Reported also by [RedHat Bug 1982746](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1982746)